# Trying to find a science-fiction horror short story collection including "The Birds" by Daphne Du Mauerier

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm not sure when it was published, but it was quite old, probably mid to late 1900s. It contained a number of short stories and poems. Its cover was red.

The only story I can concretely remember was that it had "The Birds" by Daphne du Maurier. There was also a short story I can remember hazily that was about someone dead/dying in a spaceship that was heading towards destruction. There was also a poem written by someone with the first name Arthur (I think?) who was both a poet and a government official later in his life.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

[*Something Strange*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?31129), a 1969 anthology and high school English text; published by Macmillan; edited by Marjorie B. Smiley, Mary Delores Jarmon, and Domenica Paterno. Note the red cover. Contents include [Daphne du Maurier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphne_du_Maurier)'s novelette ["The Birds"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?80267), a bunch of other stories of science fiction, fantasy, and horror, and eight poems.

Two of the poems, ["Epistle to Be Left in the Earth"](http://www.chaosbutterfly.net/library/macleish_epistle.html) and ["The End of the World"](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/the-end-of-the-world/), are by the poet [Archibald MacLeish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archibald_MacLeish), who served as [Librarian of Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Librarian_of_Congress#List_of_Librarians_of_Congress) from 1939 to 1944.

The story "about someone dead/dying in a spaceship that was heading towards destruction" could be a hazy recollection of [Tom Godwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Godwin)'s novelette ["The Cold Equations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cold_Equations), which you can [read at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v53n06_1954-08_Sirius-Starhome#page/n59/mode/2up) or [listen to the *X Minus One* radio adaptation](https://archive.org/details/OTRR_X_Minus_One_Singles/XMinusOne55-08-25015ColdEquations.mp3).

Comment: I thought it might be this one... http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?485379

Comment: It contains a story by Arthur Quiller-Couch was a noted poet who also worked for the govt. I'm only going on ISFDB and his bio though.

Comment: On inspection yours seems like the right answer. I'll hang fire

Comment: oh my gosh, that's the one! Thank you so much, you just made my night.

Comment: @key You're welcome!